# Is reading from and writing to a database a more I/O bound or CPU bound task?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

There is a huge table in one database which has to be replicated to another database. The python ETL job chunks up the table's data to ~ 10 000 rows. If I do this synchronously, it takes a lot of time, which I want to improve.
In short the task is:

1. connecting to source db and target db (both DB2 on Cloud)
2. select 10.000 rows by ID from the source table and store them in a pandas dataframe (or a simple list)
3. insert these 10.000 rows to the target table

Repeat this iteration until reaching the last record in source db.

I know that doing this on multiple threads would only cause a better performance if the tasks are I/O bound, but honestly I have no idea if there is any waiting in the process above. Can someone explain if this process is more I/O bound or CPU bound? Is it worth to try multithreading, or this would be better with multiprocessing (or the combination of the 2)?

Comment: The bottleneck for such a operation is unlikely to be the database client (your script). Start with threading & see where you run into a performance bottleneck

Comment: There are more things to look at first: do you perform each insert in a separate transaction or multiple inserts per transaction? Do you use batching?

Comment: each insert is a separate transaction with 10k records.

Comment: Where are you running the script? Also on the cloud, where the network connections between the script and the databases are fast, or on your PC, with slow connections for download and upload?

Comment: in the cloud on the same location as the database are located.

Comment: It would be great if you could show us your code - without it is guesswork. Are you using `dataframe.to_sql`? If so, have you tried `multi` method?

Comment: im using ibm_db.execute_many() which I guess works the same way as multi for to_sql. I am not inserting row by row if you were thinking about that.